# How do I use the MonkeyLearn API PHP Client to classify a sample text

Tags: php, post, monkeylearn

I have looked at https://github.com/artstorm/monkeylearn-api-php , but I can't understand how to actually send the post request via php.

Where do I put this:

```
$token = 'monkeylearn-api-token';
$client = new Artstorm\MonkeyLearn\Client($token);
$textToClassify = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
$module = 'module_id';
$response = $client->classification->classify($textToClassify, $module);
print_r($response->result());
```

What files do I need to send it?

Comment: Got it working! 
 In command prompt:  composer require monkeylearn/monkeylearn-php
 It will install the necessary folders in the cmd prompt directory you selected. Inside there is a vendor folder. In there make a test.php file. inside that file insert the php code from: https://app.monkeylearn.com/main/classifiers/cl_qkjxv9Ly/tab/api-tab/
Then run the file from your localhost and it will give you the output